# Internal Disk randomly becomes unmounted on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd

I have several hard disks in my rig. C: is an SSD, so is D:. E: and T: are both HDDs. The issue I described in the title exists with D: (and only with D:). Sometimes, when I boot up my computer, it is not there.

After restarting several times it becomes visible again. I have checked whether its assigned letter has just been reset but this is not the case either - it just does not show up, nowhere. I have installed the software "Samsung Magician" to determine whether it is damaged but no errors were found, the disk is deemed "Healthy" (it was visible of course when I ran the test).

One thing I have noticed is that when Windows takes longer to boot up than it usually does (the Windows 7 splash screen as here https://tr3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2010/06/16/093a741b-c3b0-11e2-bc00-02911874f8c8/435248.jpg) the disk will not be visible.

The issue has not arisen for quite a while now but today after being visible it randomly disappeared which I don't recall ever experiencing again.

It's a 1TB Samsung Pro SSD that is not that old and has not been used for much either (I just have a couple of games installed on it). OS is Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit.

Comment: If they're different disc (not different partition on the same disc) could it be a hardware issue (the connection)? Try installing/booting another OS to see if it's the case.

Comment: Check the disk connector (reseat it just in case). If the problem still occurs, might possibly be a bad cable or bad disk.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It would almost seem as if the OS is the culprit of the issue. I am running Windows 10 in dual-boot and when I boot into it, the disk is pretty much always there. Additionally, the disk now also often becomes unmounted after being initially visible in Windows 7 (previously, I would be there after booting or not, now it often vanishes even when the former was the case).